# RedirectToRoute causes redirect loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

```
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    return RedirectToRoute("Home");
}
```

I expect this action to redirect the user to the homepage but instead, a redirect loop occurs (according to Chrome).

The aforementioned action belongs to a controller in the "admin" area as where the "Home" route is defined for the default area - I suspect this to be relevant.

Here is the route for good measure:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Home",
    "{controller}/{action}/{slug}",
    new { controller = "Posts", action = "Index", slug = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "GoBlog.Controllers" }
);
```

**Update**

Replacing the `return` statement with the following will cause the action to work as expected:

```
return RedirectToRoute("Home", (RouteTable.Routes["Home"] as Route).Defaults);
```

I want to know why this is the case. Ideally I can omit the (cumbersome) second argument.

Comment: Can't tell what authService.Logout(); does but it might call the Logout() function

Comment: @AndrewNgo Updated the code to use a concrete implementation. Seems to be irrelevant though because the error persists without that statement.

Comment: Show your routes as configured in `RoutesConfig.cs`.

Comment: Use Fiddler to find out to what URL the user is redirected (look at the Location header). Then, find out to what URL he is redirected then. Update the question with that information.

Comment: are your `Logout` action in Posts controller?

Comment: No. `Logout` action is in Login controller.

Comment: @Grundy No. `Logout` action is in Login controller.

Comment: anyway :-) when you call redirecttoroute - for generating url used value for current controllers, actions and parameters for route patterns

Comment: @usr Pretty much what you would expect: http://i.imgur.com/Pt8xpLm.png

Comment: @CasterTroy OK, that supports the theory that the answer here proposes. Probably, your route shouldn't be called "Home" because it does not lead to the homepage. It pretty much leads to any page possible. That name is misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is particular to the call `RedirectToRoute(string)` and your particular route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Home",
    "{controller}/{action}/{slug}",
    new { controller = "Posts", action = "Index", slug = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "GoBlog.Controllers" }
);
```

What you expected was `RedirectToRoute` would populate your arbitrary route definition of `{controller}/{action}/` with the route's defined defaults:

```
controller = "Posts", action = "Index"
```

But `RedirectToRoute` like all redirect methods, is a part of your controller, and uses your **current Controller and Action** as Default Values where ever possible. This is a "feature" of the ***ASP.NET MVC*** framework -- re-using routes to create new routes. This approach is valuable because your current Controller and Action are strong hints as to your intention.

A great example of this is `RedirectToAction(string)` which assumes your current instantiated Controller is the default.

**Contrast this with:**

```
return RedirectToRoute("Home", (RouteTable.Routes["Home"] as Route).Defaults);
```

Rather than directing the framework to use it's best guess about how to populate the ambiguous wild card route, you have specifically instructed the framework to use the **Defaults** from the ***RouteTable*** for "Home" route to construct a **route** and return it as a RouteObject.

Answer (score 3):

When you call [RedirectToRoute(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783087(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This method converts the route name that is passed in routeName to a URL by using the [RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc680260(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

where pass *null* as parameter `RouteValueDictionary`. So in this case this parameters was getting from current *RequestContext* with values for *controller, action* and etc, i.e. you get url like this

```
"{controller}/{action}/{slug}"
"Login/Logout/"
```

and got redirecting loop.

when you call

```
return RedirectToRoute("Home", (RouteTable.Routes["Home"] as Route).Defaults);
```

instead [RedirectToRoute(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783087(v=vs.110).aspx) used [RedirectToRoute(String, RouteValueDictionary)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992947(v=vs.110).aspx) and in [RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc680260(v=vs.110).aspx) method you pass defaults values for that route.

Comment: Thank you. It was the amalgamation of both your answer and usr's comment that gave me the solution: define a more specific route. I am going to leave this question without a marked answer for a few days. Your answer seems to be correct but it was not self-sufficient as it reads quite poorly. I want to wait and see if somebody can post a more coherent answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is a general best practice in MVC to allow your controllers as much control as possible. There are multiple controller methods which you can use, and you should generally use the one that is the closest fit to the process you are performing.

- `return View()`. tells the controller to generate and return the specified HTML, similar to a `Server.Transfer()`.  Use for matching HTML with Actions, or when delivering static HTML without interest in the URL string.
- `Return RedirectToAction()`.  Tells the controller to build a new URL string based on the Action.  This will parse the route dictionary for the Action, and handle the defaults.  It acts as a `Response.Redirect()`, and will return a new generated URL.  In general, this is the most commonly used redirect.  This also has the benefit of not changing if the route dictionary is changed.
- `return RedirectToRoute()`.  Similar to `RedirectToAction()`, however tied to the Route Dictionary.  This will search the Route Dictionary for an exact route match, using whatever route parameters are passed.  This does not look for Actions, and thus does not build a route or inject default values.  Used when an exact route with specific non-default values must be processed.
- `return Redirect()`.  This redirect requires a full URL, and will redirect to the new URL.  Usually used when redirecting to a URL on a totally different domain.